# Via MTP on WinXP - Digitalcamera instead of Portable Device

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows-xp, mtp

I'm using Meego's MTP code ([Buteo MTP](http://meego.gitorious.org/meego-middleware/buteo-mtp) = daemon + functionfs) on a TI814X evaluation board. When connecting to Win7 it's detected as **Protable Device** and I'm offered to open the explorer. But on WinXP it's detected as **Digital Camera** and thus I get offered to open scan- and image-editors and the explorer-icon is a camera.

Preparations: I've set the device type to 0x03 ('portable device'). I gave my device a unique name and delete before each try all occurrences of this name from the registry (otherwise my changes do not appear on Windows).

I ve compared the output of 'USB View' with my Samsung Galaxy mobile, and the only difference I found is bDeviceProtocol, which is set to "1" by the mobile (against the [specification of PTP](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/usb_still_img10.pdf)). Applying this value to my hardware makes no difference.

When opening the hardware manager, I can list the `Compatible IDs`. In these IDs the Samsung mobile lists

```
USB\MS_COMP_MTP
USB\Class_06&SubClass_01&Prot_01
USB\Class_06&SubClass_01
USB\Class_06
```

while my device lacks of the first entry:

```
USB\Class_06&SubClass_01&Prot_01
USB\Class_06&SubClass_01
USB\Class_06
```

Also the service of the mobile is `WUDRFd` and of my device only `usbscan`.

**Questions:** By what is the `MS_COMP_MTP` triggered? Is it an option of my USB-/MTP-configuration or is it triggered by the vencor/product ID? How can I make my device use of `WUDRFd` instead of `usbscan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a data structure called "[Microsoft OS Descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463179.aspx)". This can be transfered to Windows by the device and causes this "MS_COMP_MTP" flag.

The current Windows versions do detect MTP without this descriptor - but Windows XP [still needs it](http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/19505/14786/#post14156).

Thanks to Peter for this [information](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg74233.html).

Comment: From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpdblog/archive/2009/08/29/mtp-over-various-transports.aspx: "Windows XP uses the Microsoft OS Descriptor to identify MTP devices; Windows Vista and Windows 7 can identify MTP devices by either the OS Descriptor or the USB Still Image Class Code (Class 6, Subclass 1, Protocol 1)."